# HTML Form not submitting any attached file

Tags: javascript, html, css, forms

my form does not take or submit any attachment file and has the enctype and method attributes inside the form element. It looks like this:

```
<form action="vsend.php" class="volunteerAppForm" method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" role="form" enctype="multipart/form-data">

<div class="fileUploadSection">
    <label for="fileToUpload">Please upload your CV</label><br>
    <input type="file" name="file" id="fileToUpload" required>
  </div>
  <div class="captcha">
    <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey="6Ld071QUAAAAAIutKo0CkibGU8oeaomD5niSfNiX"></div>
    <input type="submit" name='submit' value="send" class="submit-input" style="cursor: pointer;">
  </div>
</form>
```

Comment: Show us your php code.

Comment: What does `validateForm()` look like? Is it returning true?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

I debugged my codes, the problem was in my strings just in my php file here:

```
//Attachments
    if (
        isset($_FILES['uploaded_file']) &&
        $_FILES['uploaded_file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK
    ) {
        $mail->AddAttachment(
            $_FILES['uploaded_file']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['uploaded_file']['name']
        );
    }
```

As my input type attribute has a value "file", my string should also have the same name 'file' not 'uploaded_file' as showen above.
Could be like so:

//Attachments

```
    if (
        isset($_FILES['file']) &&
        $_FILES['file']['error'] == UPLOAD_ERR_OK
    ) {
        $mail->AddAttachment(
            $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'],
            $_FILES['file']['name']
        );
    }
```